# Is there a SharePoint 2010 virtual machine?

Tags: 2010, virtual-machine

Is there a downloadable, ready to use, virtual machine with sharepoint 2010 and all prerequisites already installed?

I just googled it but apparently it does not exist.

I just want a quick way to start making some tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure it is! Here is the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417):  It's huge because it has Project server, 
etc...

Comment: This link is now dead. Do you have any other link where it is available now?

Comment: It is likely that it's dead because it's no longer the current version of the product. I'll Google it, but I imagine that there is not an official one available for SP 2010.

Comment: I tried searching for official SP 2013 and found this link: http://gauravmahajan.net/2013/01/06/sharepoint-2013-rtm-on-win-server-2012-virtual-machine-download/. Would you recommend installing this one? Or is there any official version available?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, you may want to consider a trial hosted solution. I've recommended this to users and developers who want to test the SharePoint world with little upfront cost.

Andrew Connell has setup one [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2012/03/13/critical-path-trainingrsquos-ldquoall-uprdquo-training-vm-now-on-cloudshare.aspx) in a hosted environment. The VM is free and it looks like you can get a 14 days trial subscription to the service that hosts the VM.