# Is there a fiddle for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I am new to SharePoint

Is there a fiddle for SharePoint? Like dotnetfiddle and jsfiddle?

I have checked this question,

[Is there a SharePoint 2010 virtual machine?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/is-there-a-sharepoint-2010-virtual-machine) but the links in answers are dead now

Comment: what about the creating the VM on your PC/Laptop?

Comment: that might require a good configuration! mine is 4GB ram. So thought of exploring online fiddle first

Answer (score 7):

After some amount of research i found a site which provides free site creation online!!

https://www.cloudappsportal.com

I also managed to create a free site  :) 
[image]

This site is actually great!
**I gave this url and i was able to create sharepoint app for that site and deploy it!!**

Answer (score 2):

No based on my understanding. SharePoint is a complex server which has lots of dependencies.

What you can do is create a Developer Account in Office 365 space. Then use that for developing apps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924.aspx

Comment: looks like the free trial is only for a month

Comment: Unfortunately Yes. I would suggest you buy a dev subscription till you learn it. It will be a good investment anyway. Or you can keep on subscribing for Trial every month. The only problem is you will loose data and need to recreate it again.

Comment: oh thats great!
can i use the same account(user id) for trial every month?

Comment: Yes I believe so. Haven't tried it yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more link which i found for Virtual labs

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs?id=bkKjrNSmdAg

hope this helps.