# SharePoint 2013 virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine

Where can I find a SharePoint 2013 virtual machine that Ii can run on my pc? I need to do some basic stuff like creating sites collections and sites.

The only ones I found is some that need like 24 GB Ram and has super big requirements.

Is there something available for normal computers so I can try some stuff at home?

Comment: Does it have to be on-premise? You could always get a 30 days free subscription on office365 for evaluation. No hidden charges, and you can just leave it when you are done, and create a new one after 30 days.

Comment: @user19952 I never used Office 365 does it look and feel like the normal SharePoint environment? I really just need to do some basic stuff like putting content, creating pages, create some links and so on

Comment: For running SharePoint 2013 you really would need a lot of RAM and processing power, this is the reality. (So go the cloud wah if Office 365 if you can)

Comment: @RobertLindgren So it's free but you have to give your payment method anyway? Can you block or delete them so you're not charged after the trial period?

Comment: If you just need a development environment you can get this done with a normal PC. Mine is on my laptop (AD, SQL, SP) with 16GB RAM. Slow, but for testing alright

Comment: The details for what you can get in O 365 I can not answer. Surely you can run it on your laptop, but with some services running (like search) it will be painful

Comment: @RobertLindgren Apparently you an have SharePoint in Office 365. But i don't know if every version of Office 365 have Sharepoint. Are you aware of it please?

Comment: You can use this license for most simple development scenarios https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/jj919154.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thank you, this may work, i've suceeded creating a OFFICE 365 Developer Site and apparently i have to wait up to 24 hours to get SharePoint. This may do it. thanks for the help.

Comment: This may also help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138908/is-there-a-fiddle-for-sharepoint