# Access Sharepoint

Tags: 2013

I signed up for a sharepoint class online through a college and now I find out that I have to have access to sharepoint which I don't have.  Can I download and install this on my pc and if so where could I find this?

Comment: Is the training for SharePoint that is installed on your organizations servers (also called on-premises SharePoint) or is it for SharePoint Online (part of Office 365)? What you need will be different depending on the answer. Also, is this developer or end-user type training?

Comment: This may help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138908/is-there-a-fiddle-for-sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to familiarise yourself with SharePoint then the quickest and the easiest way to start is to sign up for a free trial of Office 365 which also includes SharePoint online.

https://www.google.com/search?q=office+365+trial

https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+2013+hardware+requirements

https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+2013+trial+download