# economical SharePoint dev environment?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, azure

I m planning to start learning SharePoint. can you please guide what can be the best way to have SharePoint  dev environment. I need to buy because my laptop only has 16 gab ram and laptop I have can maximum support 16 gab. I tried looking options and they are:

1. Buy a desktop with 32 or 64 gb ram ($900-1400).
2. Azure or other cloud base VM (not sure but roughly looks $200-300) per month

That is a good investment but want to save if I can because of being jobless. My current laptop is 16 gab ram with i7. Can you please guide what can be the best and most economical way to go.

Comment: You can definitly run you DEV environment on your laptop. Mine has also 16GB RAM and i5. SharePoint Farm (Active Directory VM (1GB RAM), SQL VM (2GB RAM) and SP VM (4GB RAM)). For testing and pure DEV it will run.

Comment: @Patrick thanks for your input. Do you face any issue or slowness ? I saw a couple of videos and they suggested 16 gab is hardly acceptable. I m new to SP is that use all or for something else I will need improved system ?

Comment: It depends. If you want to have an Frontend and Applicationserver and also an Office Web Apps Server and a dedicated Search and Workflow Server, you have to have a more powerful system. But for starting and learning it is good to go.

Comment: Maybe it's opinion based but it's a valid question and would help a lot budding developers in our community.

Comment: @user576510: Your question is closed so I can't answer below but do take a look at my next comment.

Comment: A laptop with 16gb of ram is totally acceptable for dev environment. As you are just starting to learn, for a couple of weeks you can try office 365 trial and learn about basics. 

After that when you need to do custom coding in terms of visual webparts and other custom modules laptop will suffice as your dev machine. A simple tip would be to stop search service as initially it's not required.

Also, for client side scripting and to learn CSOM and Rest  Office 365 is good enough. From my experience more and more clients are moving towards OOTB approaches with CSOM then Server side codes.

Comment: @TaranGoel I m new to this site not sure if I can chat or send you private message.  Are you saying I should install SP directly or it should be through VMware .

Comment: There are some other options too:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138908/is-there-a-fiddle-for-sharepoint

Comment: @TaranGoel, Does Office 365 Trial still exists ?